# How to find unneeded PackageReference in csproj

Tags: reference, .net-core, refactoring, csproj, code-cleanup

I am in the process of doing clean up on a project that has gone through much of the dev cycle and is almost ready to go to production. I wanted to remove any unneeded `PackageReference`s in the the `csproj` but can not seem to find any way to detect them, except to perhaps to remove each one individually and try building... is there an easy way to see which of the `PackageReference`are actually needed for your project?

Comment: I think you need an extension to make this easy. ReSharper does it quite well.

Comment: Delete a package and see if your code breaks :)

Comment: Yep... mentioned that in my description... but I wouldn't call that an "easy way". ReSharper... I shudder every time I hear the word. I actually can't stand how much slower Visual Studio starts behaving, then all of the distracting squiglies... but yes, for stuff like this it does a decent enough job.

Comment: Those "distracting" squiggles are issues with your code - ignore them at your peril!

Comment: That is not true @DavidG many of those squiggles are simply things that are not done in style or preference that JetBrains would have done it... ie conform to their coding style or get squiggles, many of them have nothing to do with any actual issues in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio Extension: [ResolveUR - Resolve Unused References](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=battas.ResolveUR-ResolveUnusedReferences) or use [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Refactorings__Remove_Unused_References.html) if you have installed it.

Comment: Interesting, though this line concerns me: "not tested to work with DotNet Web projects(Asp.Net, MVC)"